# Is variance of for generic type parameters in C# 4.0 a step closer for higher kind types?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, covariance, higher-kinded-types

We know that implementing classes are still invariant, despite the fact that their interfaces are variant. However I am inquiring, is cov/contravariance a step closer to parametric polymorphism or these are two separate concepts?

Comment: I'm not a CS guy, but from the description [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Parametric_polymorphism), C# *already* offers parametric polymorphism; it may be worth clarifying the question? i.e. what behaviour is it you are looking for?

Comment: Just updated the tags of my post. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: C# already has parametric rank-1 polymorphism. The OP is asking about higher-kinded parametric polymorphism. For example, the reason why LINQ query expressions are defined as a syntactic pattern and not as a type is that LINQ QEs are a rank-2 polymorphic type which simply *cannot* be expressed by C#. As a result, LINQ QEs are *not* type-safe, which is actually quite an embarassment given that LINQ and type-safety are two of the most touted features by C# evangelists.

Answer (score 1):

Variance is related to subtyping, not really to kinds. That said, I think you might be able to use some subtyping tricks to get some of the benefits of higher kinds. I'm still stuck with C# 3 though, so I haven't experimented with this very much, but I certainly plan to.